# Get posts by hashtag in Instagram API

Tags: instagram-api

I tried to find an answer without success.

I have an website that will show all twitter tweets and instagram posts based in a hashtag.

In twitter I authenticated userless, since I just wanted to show all tweets from a hashtag.

The problem is with Instagram, I already signed and I'm retrieving posts with:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag}/media/recent?access_token=xxx
```

But the thing is that it only retrieves tags from my posts, instead I want it to search in the Instagram universe.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It does retrieve the instagram posts **(all the posts in instagram provided the privacy of the post is set to public)**. I have successfully did it in my open source Instagram Hashtag Feed App on Windows Store Application (C#). It works exactly like searching in instagram with a hashtag.

https://github.com/ShiChuanTaylors/InstaFeed/blob/master/OrientationFeed/InstagramFeed.xaml.cs

Hope the code can help. :)